# list of vnets with connected devices in Azure portal

Tags: azure, powershell

I could not get the list of vnets in Azure portal with connected devices

i tried using powershell script to get list of vnets with the connected devices attached to it using powershell script but could not get the output .

Comment: You forgot to post your script

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of vnets in Azure portal with connected devices make use of below script:

```c
$subs = Get-AzSubscription 
foreach ($Sub in $Subs) {
    Write-Host "***************************"
    Write-Host " "
    $Sub.Name 

    $SelectSub = Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $Sub.Name

    $VNETs = Get-AzVirtualNetwork 
    foreach ($VNET in $VNETs) {
        Write-Host "--------------------------"
        Write-Host " "
        Write-Host "   vNet: " $VNET.Name 
        Write-Host "   AddressPrefixes: " ($VNET).AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes

        $vNetExpanded = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $VNET.Name -ResourceGroupName $VNET.ResourceGroupName -ExpandResource 'subnets/ipConfigurations' 

        foreach($subnet in $vNetExpanded.Subnets)
        {
            Write-Host "       Subnet: " $subnet.Name
            Write-Host "          Connected devices " $subnet.IpConfigurations.Count
            foreach($ipConfig in $subnet.IpConfigurations)
            {
                Write-Host "            " $ipConfig.PrivateIpAddress
            }
        }

        Write-Host " " 
    } 
}
```

Output:

[image]

### Update

AFAIK, you can get this detailed information using below command:

```c
$result=Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name '<vnet name>'  -ResourceGroupName '<group nmae>' -ExpandResource 'subnets/ipConfigurations' 
$result.Subnets[0].IpConfigurations
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response.Is it not possible to get connected devices name

Comment: @Anjumaara yes, Check the updated answer